# alerting when cookie is going to expire jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using cookies, i am trying to just show a alert message and a blinking status message that cookie is getting expired in like a countdown, giving them 60 seconds to click, extend it, if they do not click the link, it will navidate to the href link for expiration. and will expire the cookie.

```
<script>
//the function IdleToLong will be called after 30seconds. 
//This means if the page reloads, it starts over.
setTimeout(IdleToLong, 30 * 1000); // 30 seconds

function IdleToLong() {
  alert('Move your ass');

  //If you also need to logout in PHP then you must notify the server that a user has been idle to long.
  $.get('logout.php?reason=idle').complete(function() { 
     window.location.href = '/';
  });
}
</script>
```

the above code works but it does not display a message like a countdown from 60 backward to 0, in that alert, if they click, expend, extend the cookkie, else logout, but that alert should only appear after every 3 hours, because i am setting it for 3 hours and extending it by 3 hours

Answer (score 0):

That's not that simple, JavaScript cannot retrieve the expiration time of a Cookie in the `document.cookie` API or in the `Response` object in case of a `fetch` or `XMLHttpRequest`. So you'll have to provide the token from the backend in a readable header (or in the body). Then you'll be able with some simple logic to code the countdown in JavaScript.

To give more concrete examples, this header is not retrievable in JavaScript:

```
Set-Cookie: test=value; Path=/; Expires=Sat, 28 Mar 2020 12:48:58 GMT;
```

After this header has arrived in a HTTP response, the cookie is retrievable with `document.cookie` but without the expiration date.

On the other hand, this header is retrievable:

```
X-Whatever-Name-You-Want: test=value; Path=/; Expires=Sat, 28 Mar 2020 12:48:58 GMT;
```

So you could provide the Cookie in a custom header in order to retrieve it with JavaScript **with the expiration date**.

Comment: so you mean i store the value in the database table or ain a file with its current time and it keeps on checking that file every 5 minutes to check if the 3 hours are up or not and if up, it will then trigger a alert and give 60 seconds countdown to user to continue expand or it will expire it

Answer (score 0):

When a user visits your site and you set a cookie, you should set a second cookie containing the first cookie's expiration date. Then using JavaScript you can subtract the value of the expiration date from the current time to get your setTimeout value.

PHP:

```
$cookie_max_age = [number of seconds];
$cookie_expires = time()+$cookie_max_age;
$cookie_value = rawurlencode("[cookie value]");
header("set-cookie: [cookie name]=$cookie_value; max-age=$cookie_max_age", false);
header("set-cookie: expires=$cookie_expires; max-age=$cookie_max_age", false);
```

JavaScript:

```
var expires = parseInt(('; '+document.cookie).split('; expires=')[1]);
var interval = setInterval(function() {
    var milliseconds_left = (new Date()).getTime()-expires*1000;
    if (milliseconds_left<=0) {
        clearInterval(interval);
        $.get('logout.php?reason=idle').complete(function() { 
            window.location.href = '/';
        });
    }
    else if (milliseconds_left<=60000) {
        var messageBox = document.getElementById('messageBox');
        messageBox.innerHTML = "Your session will expire in "+(milliseconds_left/1000)+" seconds.";
    }
}, 1000);
```

Doing a countdown is a different problem. You probably want to create a lightbox with an extend button.

Comment: a sample will be the best to understand this scenario, if db is not an option, i think the filesystem will work best

Comment: What server side language are you using?

Comment: php language but any other works the same way right